# customizer options not showing

Tags: theme-customizer

I have a wordpress installation where the customize options have disappeared. I already disabled all plugins, but it did not solve the problem. What more can I do? Thanks in avance.

Comment: Have you tried switching to a default theme? Have you checked the console to see if there are JavaScript errors?